# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context when I want cal composable function in the another composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Why do I get this error when I want to separate codes of a screen to separate files and call it? how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: [Don't publish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) images of the code, publish the code itself along with the error.

Comment: Also this seems like a typo, you're padding view into `paddingValues`. This parameter expects `PaddingValues`, not a view

Answer (score 0):

Each of the 2 composables is responsible for a different part of the screen, so
you need to move `ProfileContentSection()` composable out of `TopAppBarSection` arguments - that is call them separately inside the ProfileScreen composable

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen( ... ){

//call this composable separately
TopAppBarSection (viewModel = viewModel,
modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = PaddingValues(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 13.dp)))

//call this composable separately
ProfileContentSection(viewModel = ViewModel,modifier = modifier)

.... }
```